# How to handle an offset greater than 2000 on SOQL without sorting by ID or date using the Salesforce Rest API

Tags: salesforce, limit, offset

Right now I'm working on migrating a site from using an oracle database to use salesforce. For querying the data we are using the latest version of the salesforce rest API. Right now I'm facing a problem paginating results with an offset greater than 2000. I have seen quite a few questions on this topic but none of them seem to fit my problem.

So Here are the restrictions

- I need to fetch the results on chunks of 20 records (that is the page size). I can't just get a bunch of results and then do some manual pagination because that would be out of scope for the project.
- I can't do something like `WHERE ID > lastIdIntheResults LIMIT 20` because I need to sort my results by Name, sorting by Id would break the order that the client expects.
- Needs to be done using the REST API. I don't think there is a way to use queryMore function on the REST API.

So, do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST API's equivalent of SOAP API's `queryMore` is `done: false` and `nextRecordsUrl: ...` in the response.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm

Here's my data queried via https://workbench.developerforce.com -> Utilities -> Rest Explorer:

[image: Workbench showing REST API explorer with "SELECT Id FROM Quote" that returns 11K records using the described technique]

And then the next one would be

[image]

And to change the "chunk size" without LIMIT/OFFSET you can use a HTTP header: [`Sforce-Query-Options: batchSize=200`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_queryoptions.htm)

Comment: Hi @eyescream. Thanks for the response. Is these the only way to do what I described above? I do see the next records URL, but according to the documentation the Sforce-Query-Options has a minimum value of 200. Our page size is 20

Comment: That's what out of the box and protecting resources (check Setup -> Company information what's your daily limit of API calls in prod, in sandbox it'll be much higher. You don't want this pagesize = 20 to cause issues in prod if you have millions of records to sync). Have you considered `SELECT ... WHERE Id > x ORDER BY Name, Id`? That'd solve your sorting expectation and be safe, no skipped records....

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the limit issue. Also I will check the results of sorting by ID. Thanks a lot