# Pagination for results generated on hitting salesforce API by third party system

Tags: pagination, salesforce, apex

I am trying to implement pagination with the below scenario:

Third party system is hitting salesforce API and returning the result from an object in salesforce.
They want to get the results paginated and get the response from salesforce by passing below parameters from their end:

PageIndex/No
PageSize

I dont necessarily have to display the records using VisualForce/LWC,etc.Just the paginated records need to be passed back to 3rd party system.
All the resources I found on the web employ using some VF page,component,etc.If there is a necessity of using the same for implementing this pagination,please do let me know that as well.

Tried looking for resources where pagination can be implemented but the resources involve using a VF page,lightning component,etc

I expected: A simple pagination on the records being returned from the salesforce webservice

Answer (score 0):

For smaller data sets you can use SOQL's LIMIT and [OFFSET](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm). You can offset (skip) up to 2000 records that way.

More general solution would be to use salesforce's "query locators" (bit like CURSOR statement in a normal database). You need to read up about [queryMore()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm) (if you use SOAP API) to get next chunk of data (no jumping around with page number, just next, next...)

REST API has similar nextRecordsUrl: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56448825/313628

If they can't implement that / you don't want to give access to normal API, just some Apex... at most you can query 50K records in 1 transaction so you could make-do something that way. You'll likely need to put some rules around fixed order of records